# ftp *.[cC][sS][vV] not working as intended on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ftp

One of my client's ftp server recently moved from Linux to Windows.

Searching using `*.[cC][sS][vV]` looks for *.csv and *.CSV files as intended on Linux.

[image]

But this doesn't work on Windows. Is there a way to expand this correctly on Windows or perform a case-insensitive search on Windows ftp server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP specification does not allow any filemasks.

While some FTP servers do support this, you cannot rely on this functionality, if your script has to be platform-independent.

The Windows IIS FTP server does not support file masks. Even if it did, it would not support the set syntax (`[]`), as that's not supported in Windows file masks in general.

See also [Get File Listing ending with A or B using Jscape FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28179920/850848).

You have to retrieve all files (without any mask) and filter them locally in your code/script.